# 'undefined symbol: SSL_get_servername' message when starting Apache Web Server

Tags: apache2, webserver, openssl, mod-ssl

I installed httpd-2.2.16 and openssl-1.0.0 on Red Hat Linux 5: when starting the Apache a 'undefined symbol: SSL_get_servername' message is generated on the command line.

Listed below are the parameters used for the Apache installation (section A) and the generated error message when Apache is started (SECTION B).

Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution? Googling and Binging did not produce a solution that seems to fit this case (theyare Mandiva/Suse specific)

SECTION A) Parameters entered for installation:

./configure --prefix=/usr/apache --with-ldap --enable-mods-shared="all ssl ldap cache proxy authn_alias mem_cache file_cache authnz_ldap charset_lite dav_lock disk_cache" --with-ssl=/usr/openssl

SECTION B) Error generated when Apache is started (entering '/apachectl start'):

httpd: Syntax error on line 103 of /usr/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/apache/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /usr/apache/modules/mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: SSL_get_servername

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling with the modules you need explicitly - I ran into the same issue previously, not sure what triggered it - I recompiled with modules I needed explicitly and it worked. The draw back is you have to recompile Apache if you require additional modules down the road.